# Cut some part of a cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my query

> select CONTACTNAME,EMAIL from CONTACTS result

```
contactname           email
Sysadmin        admin@gmail.com
Dybwad          adrian@yahoo.com
```

Is that possible that i can have the results emails only the domain part rest same  e.g.

```
  contactname           email
    Sysadmin            gmail.com
    Dybwad              yahoo.com
```

Comment: Yes, combine substring with position.

Comment: the part before @ is not same for all

Comment: e.g.  it can be  "admin@gmail.com" or "a@gmail.com" or "adsdfmifsdnfdfdsfsdfafadsfadsfda@gmail.com" so we can rely on possitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe using substring

```
select CONTACTNAME, SUBSTRING (EMAIL,CHARINDEX('@',EMAIL,0)+1,LEN(EMAIL)) as Email
from CONTACTS result
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually very easy, you need to use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` functions of SQL server:

Check the below query:

```
Select CONTACTNAME, SUBSTRING(EMAIL, CHARINDEX('@', EMAIL)+1, LEN(EMAIL))  from CONTACTS result
```

More Info on [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) and [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Comment: If my answer helped, you can accept the answer by select CHECK and UPVOTE it